# Json variable by php to javascript with ajax not in the right time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an input form, where the user place a link. The php check the link, then send the link, through ajax, to javascript. At the end (for debug motivation now) javascript print the url in a div.

Main trouble: the link printed is ever the previously tested (the first time write nothing) and only for a sec. But in the hidden div where the php echo the json (not used, but i'm not able to not print it on the page) is the right link.

I've tried to place javascript under, over the php, and also the two in the same time, but nothing.

I've the temptation to do this site only with the client side part and without ajax, also if is it not secure.

```
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", linkfuction, false);
function linkfuction {  
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "http://localhost/script/validate.php",
datatype: "json",
success:function(data) {
    var b1 = JSON.parse(data);
    var link3 = b1.a1;
    var link2 = b1.a2;
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = link3 ;}})}
```

php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['general-link'])) {
$url = $_POST['general-link'];
$url2 = false;
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) == TRUE and strstr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST), 'example.com') == TRUE and strstr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME), 'https') == TRUE) { $url2 = true;} else { $url2 = false;}; 
$array1 = array("a1"=>$url, "a2"=>$url2);
echo json_encode($array1);
}
?>
```

I hope it is not too personal or other.

EDIT: as requested (the div "1 have nothing of strange if not when the javascript function is called)

```
<div id="1" style=" padding-top: 1rem; padding-bottom: 1rem;"> Some text  here</div>
<div style="padding-bottom: 1rem;"> <form method="post"><input type="text" name="general-link"><input type= "submit" id="link" value="Download"></form></div>
```

Comment: seriously i cant understand a thing :( what are you trying to say. and where are you `posting` variable `general-link` via `ajax` ?

Comment: No, i use ajax only to send the php/json variable to javascript.

Comment: Can you please provide the markup that is related to this question?  As it is I have no way of knowing if `document.getElementById("1")` is valid.

Comment: "i use ajax only to send the php/json variable to javascrip".  No, you aren't currently posting _any_ data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that your #link element is probably an anchor, onclick, it refresh the page (link to itself), that's why you see your result only for a second.

Also, it's better to use :

```
function linkfunction(){...}
```

instead of :

```
function linkfunction{...}
```

Here, with fake json as b1, it works : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/xpXdxB

Comment: It's right, i must will understand how to not refresh the page ^^ Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick hacked working example (please learn from it):

```php
// validate.php
$url = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'general-link', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
$hostCheck = false;
$isHttps = false;

if($url) {
    $hostCheck = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) === 'example.com';
    $isHttps = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) === 'https';
}

echo json_encode([
    "a1" => $url,
    "a2" => $hostCheck && $isHttps
]);
```

```html
<!-- check-link form -->
<form id="check-link">
    <input type="url" name="general-link">
    <button>Download</button>
</form>
```

```js
$('#check-link').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // simplified with jQuery.post
    // "this" is the form
    $.post('http://localhost/script/validate.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        // EVER use .text() when possible!
        $("#result").text(data.a1);
    }, 'json');
});
```